# Date based partitioning

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a `last_update` column, I want to add a partition based on the `last_update` column to remove old values.

My problem is that I have a unique key in the table which does not include the `last_update` column.

What are my options?

Should I change the way I work with this table and remove the unique index?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `fileso` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'code',
  `sha256` binary(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
  `fileName` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
  `fullPath` varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
  `datein` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `uniqueness` binary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueness` (`uniqueness`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The unique key is an Hash representation of a couple of columns in the table(sha256, fullPath,hostId).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and explain the "unique key".  If it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, there is no problem; I will explain why.

Comment: @Rick James please check my update

Comment: Wtf..   `uniqueness binary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'` that seems like a red flag, why don't you just permit null values, and set it null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to remove 'old' records, then you are defeating the "uniqueness" of `uniqueness` -- since you cannot check against already-deleted rows.

So, make that just a `INDEX`, not `UNIQUE`.

Meanwhile, of what use is `id`?  You may as well promote `uniqueness` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Yeah, this contradicts my previous recommendation.)

But, back to the question of `PARTITIONing` forcing the inclusion of `last_update` on all unique keys...

Plan A:

```
no `id`
PRIMARY KEY (uniqueness, last_update)
```

Uniqueness would need to be checked with a `SELECT`, not `INSERT IGNORE`.

Plan B:

```
no `id`
INDEX (uniqueness)
```

This has problems in Replication and other situations when you need to specifically identify a row.

Plan C:

```
keep `id`
PRIMARY KEY(id, last_update)
INDEX(uniqueness)
```

Uniqueness would need to be checked with a `SELECT`, not `INSERT IGNORE`.

I prefer Plan A, unless there is somthing to indicate that `id` is necessary.

Meanwhile, see my advice on using `PARTITIONing` for a sliding dataset -- [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

**Addenda**

With Plan A, do something like this to prevent a race condition:

```
BEGIN;
$result = SELECT uniqueness FROM tbl WHERE uniqueness = $x FOR UPDATE;
if $result, you have a dup; ROLLBACK and do whatever is appropriate.
INSERT INTO tbl (...) VALUES (...);
COMMIT;
```

Be sure to check for errors at each step -- deadlocks and timeouts can happen (rarely).  If so, start over at the `BEGIN`.

If practical, consider batching the `SELECT` and `INSERT` so you can check and insert multiple rows at the same time.  (I assume dups are rare?)