# MySQL - InnoDB - Partitioning a table with uniqueness

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning

Following a previous post I posted: [date-based-partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187968/date-based-partitioning)

This is my solution for partitioning a table with primary key.

I wanted to add partitioning by months and delete old record.

```
CREATE TABLE `filesoi` (
  `uniqueness` binary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
  `sha256` binary(32) NOT NULL,
  `datein` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lastSeen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`uniqueness`),
  KEY `lastSeen` (`lastSeen`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Is this a good solution to create the table like so?:

```
CREATE TABLE `filesoi` (
  `uniqueness` binary(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
  `sha256` binary(32) NOT NULL,
  `datein` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lastSeen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `__month` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT month(curdate()),
  PRIMARY KEY (`uniqueness`,`__month`),
  KEY `lastSeen` (`lastSeen`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(`__month`)
(PARTITION `p0` VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p1` VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p2` VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p3` VALUES LESS THAN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p4` VALUES LESS THAN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p5` VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

This way I can still insert with `Insert Ignore..` and the duplicates will be per partition.

Comment: @Rick James what do you think of this solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my answer to the other Question, I was assuming you wanted to add `PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(updated_at))` and then `DROP PARTITION` to rapidly delete "old" records.

The Question here talks about using `PARTITION BY COLUMNS(_month)`.  There is essentially no difference.  However, what do you expect to happen after you finish with month #12?  Move on to 13?

I don't see a way to get a one-step uniqueness check *and* have partitioning.  I do provide some non-partition `DELETE` optimizations [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) .  That will let you use a `UNIQUE` key and have *some* performance in the deletion process.

`PRIMARY KEY (uniqueness, __month)` provides a uniqueness constraint on the pair, but *not* `uniqueness` by itself.  One failing of `PARTITIONing` is the inability to declare something unique across all partitions (unless the partition key is part of it).

If you ever need to search across a range of months, you can't do it across December to January.

Comment: I don't plan to `DROP` partition, I will truncate partition instead, where each month is an actual calendary month. what do you think?  also what do you mean by `one-step` uniqueness, i manage to work it out using compound index `PRIMARY KEY (`uniqueness`,`__month`)`

Comment: @omri - I added a couple of paragraphs.